# Why do <button> in <label> trigger click twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*For some reason, I have nested two buttons in a label. Each button will trigger some logic. But somehow I found the second button would trigger the logic of both buttons (Tested in FF and Safari on Mac. It works in Chrome, but when mouse down on the second button, both buttons will present as if they are pressed.)*

Here is a very simple sample to reproduce the problem.

HTML:

```
<label>
    abc
    <button type="button">button1</button>
    <button type="button">button2</button>
</label>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

When click on button1, all good.

When click on button2, you will see that button2's alert shows up followed by button1's.

Can anyone advise why this is happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/3X66R/

**Add:**

1. The easiest solution might be moving buttons out of the label. But I don't understand the rationale behind it and am eager to know what is happening here.
2. I think this is something standard in HTML and SHOULD happen across all browsers. But somehow Chrome has done something special to prevent it. But as you see the clicking state still shows that both buttons have been triggered.

Comment: BTW, I know moving buttons out of label tag will fix the problem. Just be curious why that is happening.

Comment: Fiddle is working fine.

Comment: It's working fine for me in that fiddle. Button 1 brings up Button 1's alert, Button 2 brings up Button 2's alert only.

Comment: @Everyone saying the fiddle works fine, it triggers twice in firefox

Comment: liar.............its working fine.

Comment: I faced alerting both button text when clicked button2. Using firefox!

Comment: Are you clicking the label by chance?

Comment: Yes in firefox...2 alerts are shown on click of 2nd button.

Comment: I have to ask. Why have you got buttons inside a `label`? Where's the semantic reasoning behind this?

Comment: That's strange. If I hover over the button2, it highlights both the buttons. Probably something related to inline property of label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because labels work as a focus control. If you put a textbox in it; it will get focus if you click the textbox or the label. Since it sees button 1 as its focus control it will get triggered by a click on the label. Button 2 is a child of the label too, so this will trigger a event on the label and by that the event on button 1 aswell

If you move one button out of the label it will work, or a prevent default will do fine too

Edit: [use of labels](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Comment: +1 for the explanation. But why this is not observed in Chrome?

Comment: @TejasJayasheel Im not sure, basicly a label should only have 1 focus control because if there are more than 1 there is no way it can know which one to focus. Perhaps Chrome is handling this better then Firefox by simply ignoring the label events on a second control. But this is simply speculation

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Its not working after clicking on first button and then on second button, event is bubbling to click on button 2, but after implement `preventDefault()` its working fine.

Comment: So, this is preventing the `click` event from the label from firing - the browser must send click events on the label to all children?

Comment: @RGraham i tried in Firefox latest version, first i click on button1 then get single alert, after that i click on button2 then get two alert that should be one.

Answer (score 0):

```
** Jquery Code **

$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(e){
        alert($(this).text());
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Updated Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/3X66R/1/